# Sharepoint Application not running

Tags: sharepoint, iis, admin-rights

I have this sharepoint application which was running absolutely fine. The Application Pool Identity was set to configurable for this sharepoint application.

But from yesterday i have been getting the following error while trying to access the application:

```
Cannot connect to the configuration database.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: Cannot connect to the configuration database.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[WebPartPageUserException: Cannot connect to the configuration database.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.EnsureInitialize(HttpRequest request) +544
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.BeginRequestHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea) +2347
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

The application had the credentials of a user who has now left our organization. So i decided to key in my credentials for the same.
But i am still facing the same error !!

I have given all the rights to my user that the other user had under the user management (administrative tools).

Can someone please help !!
Whats going wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that your application pool account has "Connect" permission on the SharePoint_Config database.

Comment: I know i could be a stupid asking this...but how do i do the above said..kindly help

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio on the database server. http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/sql-server-2005/sql-sever-management-studio-part-1.html

Comment: When connected via Management Studio, locate Sharepoint_Config and check Properties > Permission and verify/set the application pool permisssions.